# addClass/removeClass to a SubClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to javascript and still learning the ropes. I am trying to use addClass to a subclass

I assumed that this would work:

```
jQuery('#wrow .text').addClass("error"); 
jQuery('#wrow .text').removeClass("error");
```

But it doesn't ? Little unsure how to do this to subclasses ? I am sure you gurus will help in a jiffy! :)

**Edit:** I am actually using

```
jQuery('#wrow_' + nameSpace + '.text').addClass("error");
```

but it isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried debugging jQuery('#wrow' + nameSpace + '.text').length to make sure it is returning the objects you expect?

Comment: *make sure it is returning a value greater than 0

Comment: This is a little smelly--I encourage you to post more of you html/js--there might be a better way.

Comment: ok figured it out :P was a problem with the order of classes :) - thanks for the help guys - i was bashing my head against the wall!

Comment: You mean the order of your CSS definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps describe a little bit more as to what you're trying to accomplish?

```
$('#wrow .text').addClass("error"); 
$('#wrow .text').removeClass("error");
```

Will take any descendent of #wrow with the .text class and add the error class to those elements.

If you want to find the #wrow element when it also has the class "text", then it should look like this:

```
$('#wrow.text').addClass("error"); // no space in the selector
```

I don't think that's what you want either because you'd really only have one #wrow in the page (if you have more, you have another problem as IDs are supposed to be unique) so please clarify.

Comment: hey :) thanks for the response - yeah i am actually doing

jQuery('#wrow' + nameSpace + '.text').addClass("error"); 

but it aint working ?

Answer (score 3):

If this is your actual code

```
jQuery('#wrow_' + nameSpace + '.text').addClass("error");
```

Then I suspect you're missing a space

```
jQuery('#wrow_' + nameSpace + ' .text').addClass("error");
// put a space right here -----^
```

Answer (score 0):

how does your html looks like. I'm just guessing that .text is child element of #wrow?

```
jQuery('#wrow > .text').addClass("error"); 
jQuery('#wrow > .text').removeClass("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#wrow_' + nameSpace + '.text').addClass("error");
```

What is nameSpace?  Will it actually contain a space? If not you may need a space on one or both sides